# Using NA as index when extracting from a vector

Tags: r, na, subset

In the following code:

```
x <- 1:8
x[NA]
```

I was expecting a `TRUE` or `FALSE` answer but I got eight `NA` instead. I discovered the `is.na` provides the `TRUE`/`FALSE` that I was looking for. However, I'm still not certain why subsetting the vector with `NA` results in `NA`. Any explanation?

Answer (score 5):

From the **NAs in indexing** section of `help("[")`:

> When extracting, a numerical, logical or character `NA` index picks an unknown element and so returns `NA` in the corresponding element of a logical, integer, numeric, complex or character result, and ``NULL for a list. (It returns `00` for a raw result.)

So here is what's happening in your code:

In `x[NA]` you are basically doing the same operation as you would if you did `x[]` (which simply returns all elements as they are structured in `x`), except you are picking 8 *unknown* elements and returning `NA` for each of them. The `NA` is repeatedly used for each element in `x`. In R this is called **recycling**.

As @thelatemail notes in the comments below, this can be further illustrated if we look at an example.

```
x[c(TRUE, NA, TRUE)]
# [1]  1 NA  3  4 NA  6  7 NA
```

The above code is recycling `c(TRUE, NA, TRUE)` for all the elements in `x`, where `TRUE` means "take this value".  Since we only have 8 elements in `x`, the third cycle cuts off at `NA`.

Comment: Yep. `NA` is being recycled and all `NA`s returned. Just like if you do `x[c(TRUE,NA)]` you get interspersed `NA`s with the values of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

You used NA in the place of an index.  In fact, the only valid indexes are 1-8 for your array.  x[NA] has the same value as x[9] - it's NA.